# How do I confine object creation to the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/goldrunt/SeAGU/33/
Lines 24-40 are meant to limit circle creation to the canvas. I need to check the location before allowing the new object to be created. How would I do this if the object doesn't exist yet?

```
function isAtWall(a) {
    return (a.x - a.radius <= rect.left || a.y + a.radius >= rect.top || a.x + a.radius >= rect.left + canvas.width || a.y - a.radius <= rect.top - canvas.height);
}

window.onmousedown = function (e) {
    // IE fixer
    e = e || window.event;
    // get event location on page offset by canvas location
    var location = {
        x: e.pageX - offset.x,
        y: e.pageY - offset.y
    };
    if (!isAtWall(location)) {
        create(location);
    }
};
```

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it simpler to start off with and you'll get to the answer much easier:

```
function isAtWall(a) { 

  if ((a.x >= 0 && a.x <= rect.width) && (a.y >= 0 && a.y <= rect.height))
  {
    return false;
  }

return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeAGU/35/

That will only allow the user to place circles on the canvas.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm deliberately leaving out the circle radius calculation. This function will only determine if the click event is on the canvas.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I don't need to recalculate the location plus the canvas offset since it's done already. I can just use 0 on location.x

Comment: Exactly. You could make the radius constant accessible in some way if you wanted to add in the radius to the mouse click event location. This would be problematic if you start doing circles of different sizes though. Hope this helps!